# Why should I wait to turn in items for "turn-in" (Gather Items) FATEs?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

For FATEs such as [Iron Contra Affair](http://ffxiv.gamerescape.com/wiki/Iron_Contra_Affair) in Western La Noscea, or [Let Them Eat Cactus](http://ffxiv.gamerescape.com/wiki/Let_them_Eat_Cactus) in Central Thanalan, which require you to gather items, and turn them in to an NPC, is it better to turn the items in as soon as I get them, or gather them to turn them in later?

Answer (score 7):

While *you* may be grinding FATEs for bulk XP, Company Seals, or atmas, "turn-in" FATEs can be a great source of XP for everyone else. While the FATE is going, enemies will continue to spawn for  the fifteen minutes. If the turn-in goal is met, the counter will instantly go to 1:00, forcing everyone to stop what they're doing and turn in what they got, and stop the gravy train of endless XP. Try to turn in your items when the counter is below two minutes for maximum karmic gameplay.